# External script to trigger _postback for icon button on a webpage using keyboard shortcut extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using a keyboard shortcut extension in Chrome (latest version) to save time on repetitive browser actions.

One such action: #'s in a form, hitting "Enter", an icon button appears that when clicked triggers `hreference=_postback`.. and takes me to a different page.

How do I create an external script that uses "Enter" as the keyboard shortcut which submits the form & triggers the postback (or creates a click event which does that) on the generated icon button to take me to the page clicking would normally do?

Screenshots and names to follow in a 8 hours.

Comment: The code for the form submission is <a id="btnSearchExisting" class="btn btn-primary" href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$cphMain$btnSearchExisting", "", true, "vgExistingLookup", "", false, true))'><i class="icon-search icon-white"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Search</a>   And the code for the button that pops up is: <a class="icon-zoom-in" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$gvPatents','select$0')"></a>'

Comment: Extension used: Shortcut Manager for Chrome